# Safari display question marks

Tags: character-encoding, safari

I have a website that displays fine with IE and Firefox.

But the menus are replaced by question marks when using Safari (I have been told, not having Safari on my PC).

Here is the home page (get rid of spaces):

www.v u b r i d g e.com

Any help welcome.

BTW, is there any Safari emulation for Windows based PC?

Comment: And by the way, Safari also exists for PC : http://www.apple.com/safari/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any question mark on your web page, even on the French version. If there is a problem, it's an encoding problem. Check that all your files are encoded in iso-8859-1 (the text encoding you declared in the meta html tag on your web page). If they are, then it could be your server that say the client the content is encoded in utf-8 or any other text encoding. In order to fix it, just configure the header content-type and charset to the correct value. (I've seen your website is made out of aspx which I don't know, but in php it would be `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1;");`, to be placed before any output)

Comment: Thanks for your time :-) Well, if you can see the menus - Home - Clubs - Tourneys etc. on the left part of the page, then all is well.